# vim regex - word doesn't start with

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to add a regex for ctrlp-funky for typescript functions but it is catching if and switch.
How do I modify this regex to not include words that are `if` or `switch` or function calls containing `{}`.

```
\v\s*\w+\s*\(.*\{
```

It should be able to match these

```
greet() {
ifExists() {
public static greet(a: any) {
```

but should exclude. (notice the spaces and `{` inside `(`).

```
if (x) {
if(x) {
switch (x) {
helloworld({a: null});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work a little better:

```
\v\s*<(for>|if>|switch>|while>)@!\w+\s*\(.{-}\)\s*\{
```

- `<` and `>` are word boundaries. They will match at the left and right edge of a word.
- `@!` is a negative look-ahead. It will match the the content does not follow.
- `{-}` is a lazy repeat, zero or more times. Similar to `*`, but will match as little as possible.

It will match any function-call pattern that does not match a keyword.

It is not perfect, since it does not match nested parentheses properly. That is not possible with just regular expressions in vim. For example:

```
foo(lock(foo) { })
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I have no idea you work with what kind of files, you could use **post_extract_hook** which is an undocumented, actually.
I guess what you want to do is similar to java's one below:
https://github.com/tacahiroy/ctrlp-funky/blob/master/autoload/ctrlp/funky/ft/java.vim#L22

Pull requests are always appreciated :)

Comment: it was for typescript